# Are upvotes not giving points right now?

Tags: support, reputation

I was working on enhancing my answer in [Measuring and documenting internet speed (download and upload)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253872/measuring-and-documenting-internet-speed-download-and-upload) when I noticed I got an upvote, but the counter did not give the +5, +10 or whatever the points are for an upvote. Just to verify I went to the reputation page and saw this:

[image]

Did the system freeze the point, is there some maintenance right now? I thought it was the point limit (reputation limit) but since that is very rare to happen to me, what else could it be?

Comment: Seriously... you never noticed this? You're at almost 33K already!

Comment: No, never happened before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are at the daily reputation limit. (Congratulations!)

A user can only earn 200 reputation per day, *not counting accepts and bounties*. So far for today you have zero reputation from bounties, and 30 points from accepts (two of your answers were accepted).

Therefore, except for any further accepts or bounties, the maximum reputation you can earn today is 230. Which is what you're at.

So, not a bug. Just the way the system is intended to work. For more information, see:

- [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Comment: Thanks buddy. I really thought it was something related to the maintenance done yesterday (Or was it 2 days ago?).